# How many lithium cells are there in a MacBook Pro 15"?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I'm interested in finding out how many lithium cells the battery of a MacBook Pro 15" (2015 year's model) contains.

The background to the question is that I'm interested in mailing a MacBook, within Europe, and realized that lithium batteries are classified as *dangerous goods*. From what I understand, the rules for packing and labelling  are governed by the International Air Transport Association (IATA). Furthermore, my understanding is that the number of lithium cells determine how you're supposed to pack and label the shipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has 6 cells.  However, they are of varying sizes.

[image: MacBook Pro 15" Battery]

I was able to find a [shipping resource in the EU](http://quick.aero/quickintl/blog/shipping-laptop-computers-packaging-labeling-documentation-requirements) that addresses shipping laptops:

> Scenario 2: A package with a total of 3 or more lithium ion batteries
>   contained inside of or with laptops.
>
> There is a label required on the box (see below), and the box itself
>   must be of such strength as to not break or allow the batteries to
>   come out or expel fumes, in other words, a good strong industrial box.

[image]

> **Documentation Requirements**
>
> A document is also required indicating the following
>
> - The package contains lithium ion batteries
> - The package must be handled with care and that a flammability hazard exists if the packaged is damaged
> - If the package is damaged then special procedures including inspection and repacking may be necessary
> - A telephone number to call for additional information